# Pandas groupby, resample, calculate pct_change and the store result back into original freq. dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, resampling

I have a dataframe of daily stock data, which is indexed by a datetimeindex.

There are multiple stock entries, thus there are duplicate datetimeindex values.

I am looking for a way to:

1. Group the dataframe by the stock symbol
2. Resample the prices for each symbol group into monthly price frequency data
3. Perform a pct_change calculation on each symbol group monthly price
4. Store it as a new column 'monthly_return' in the original dataframe.

I have been able to manage the first three operations. Storing the result in the original dataframe is where I'm having some trouble.

To illustrate this, I created a toy dataset which includes a 'dummy' index (idx) column which I use to assist creation of the desired output later on in the third code block.

```py
    import random
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    datelist = pd.date_range(pd.datetime(2018,1,1), periods=PER).to_pydatetime().tolist() * 2
    ids = [random.choice(['A', 'B']) for i in range(len(datelist))]
    prices = random.sample(range(200), len(datelist))
    idx = range(len(datelist))
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=zip(idx, ids, prices), index=datelist, columns='idx label prices'.split())

    print(df1.head(10))
```

df1

```py
                idx label  prices
    2018-01-01    0     B      40
    2018-01-02    1     A     190
    2018-01-03    2     A     159
    2018-01-04    3     A      25
    2018-01-05    4     A      89
    2018-01-06    5     B     164
    ...
    2018-01-31   30     A     102
    2018-02-01   31     A     117
    2018-02-02   32     A     120
    2018-02-03   33     B      75
    2018-02-04   34     B     170
    ...
```

Desired Output

```
                 idx label  prices  monthly_return
    2018-01-01    0     B      40        0.000000
    2018-01-02    1     A     190        0.000000
    2018-01-03    2     A     159        0.000000
    2018-01-04    3     A      25        0.000000
    2018-01-05    4     A      89        0.000000
    2018-01-06    5     B     164        0.000000
    ...
    2018-01-31   30     A     102       -0.098039
    2018-02-01   31     A     117        0.000000
    2018-02-02   32     A     120        0.000000
    ...
    2018-02-26   56     B     152        0.000000
    2018-02-27   57     B       2        0.000000
    2018-02-28   58     B      49       -0.040816
    2018-03-01   59     B     188        0.000000
    ...
    2018-01-28   89     A      88        0.000000
    2018-01-29   90     A      26        0.000000
    2018-01-30   91     B     128        0.000000
    2018-01-31   92     A     144       -0.098039
    ...
    2018-02-26  118     A      92        0.000000
    2018-02-27  119     B     111        0.000000
    2018-02-28  120     B      34       -0.040816
    ...
```

What I have tried so far is:

```py
    dfX = df1.copy(deep=True)
    dfX = df1.groupby('label').resample('M')['prices'].last().pct_change(1).shift(-1)
    print(dfX)
```

Which outputs:

```py
    label            
    A      2018-01-31   -0.067961
           2018-02-28   -0.364583
           2018-03-31    0.081967
    B      2018-01-31    1.636364
           2018-02-28   -0.557471
           2018-03-31         NaN
```

This is quite close to what I would like to do, however I am only getting pct_change data on end of month dates back which is annoying to store back in the original dataframe (df1) as a new column.

Something like this doesn't work:

```py
    dfX = df1.copy(deep=True)
    dfX['monthly_return'] = df1.groupby('label').resample('M')['prices'].last().pct_change(1).shift(-1)
```

As it yields the error:

```py
    TypeError: incompatible index of inserted column with frame index
```

I have considered 'upsampling' the monthly_return data back into a daily series, however this could likely end up causing the same error mentioned above since the original dataset could be missing dates (such as weekends). Additionally, resetting the index to clear this error would still create problems as the grouped dfX does not have the same number of rows/frequency as the original df1 which is of daily frequency.

I have a hunch that this can be done by using multi-indexing and dataframe merging however I am unsure how to go about doing so.

Comment: provide data for a few complete months for each label ans input data. If not full, it should at-least include the data on the last day of the month

Answer (score 1):

This generates my desired output, but it isn't as clean of a solution as I was hoping for

df1 is generated the same as before (code given in question):

```py
                idx label  prices
    2018-01-01    0     A     145
    2018-01-02    1     B      86
    2018-01-03    2     B     141
    ...
    2018-01-25   86     B      12
    2018-01-26   87     B      71
    2018-01-27   88     B     186
    2018-01-28   89     B     151
    2018-01-29   90     A     161
    2018-01-30   91     B     143
    2018-01-31   92     B      88
    ...
```

Then:

```py
    def fun(x):
        dates = x.date
        x = x.set_index('date', drop=True)
        x['monthly_return'] = x.resample('M').last()['prices'].pct_change(1).shift(-1)
        x = x.reindex(dates)
        return x

    dfX = df1.copy(deep=True)
    dfX.reset_index(inplace=True)
    dfX.columns = 'date idx label prices'.split()

    dfX = dfX.groupby('label').apply(fun).droplevel(level='label')
    print(dfX)
```

Which outputs the desired result (unsorted):

```py
                idx label  prices  monthly_return
    date                                         
    2018-01-01    0     A     145             NaN
    2018-01-06    5     A      77             NaN
    2018-01-08    7     A      48             NaN
    2018-01-09    8     A      31             NaN
    2018-01-11   10     A      20             NaN
    2018-01-12   11     A      27             NaN
    2018-01-14   13     A     109             NaN
    2018-01-15   14     A     166             NaN
    2018-01-17   16     A     130             NaN
    2018-01-18   17     A     139             NaN
    2018-01-19   18     A     191             NaN
    2018-01-21   20     A     164             NaN
    2018-01-22   21     A     112             NaN
    2018-01-23   22     A     167             NaN
    2018-01-25   24     A     140             NaN
    2018-01-26   25     A      42             NaN
    2018-01-30   29     A     107             NaN
    2018-02-04   34     A       9             NaN
    2018-02-07   37     A      84             NaN
    2018-02-08   38     A      23             NaN
    2018-02-10   40     A      30             NaN
    2018-02-12   42     A      89             NaN
    2018-02-15   45     A      79             NaN
    2018-02-16   46     A     115             NaN
    2018-02-19   49     A     197             NaN
    2018-02-21   51     A      11             NaN
    2018-02-26   56     A     111             NaN
    2018-02-27   57     A     126             NaN
    2018-03-01   59     A     135             NaN
    2018-03-03   61     A      28             NaN
    2018-01-01   62     A     120             NaN
    2018-01-03   64     A     170             NaN
    2018-01-05   66     A      45             NaN
    2018-01-07   68     A     173             NaN
    2018-01-08   69     A     158             NaN
    2018-01-09   70     A      63             NaN
    2018-01-11   72     A      62             NaN
    2018-01-12   73     A     168             NaN
    2018-01-14   75     A     169             NaN
    2018-01-15   76     A     142             NaN
    2018-01-17   78     A      83             NaN
    2018-01-18   79     A      96             NaN
    2018-01-21   82     A      25             NaN
    2018-01-22   83     A      90             NaN
    2018-01-23   84     A      59             NaN
    2018-01-29   90     A     161             NaN
    2018-02-01   93     A     150             NaN
    2018-02-04   96     A      85             NaN
    2018-02-06   98     A     124             NaN
    2018-02-14  106     A     195             NaN
    2018-02-16  108     A     136             NaN
    2018-02-17  109     A     134             NaN
    2018-02-18  110     A     183             NaN
    2018-02-19  111     A      32             NaN
    2018-02-24  116     A     102             NaN
    2018-02-25  117     A      72             NaN
    2018-02-27  119     A      38             NaN
    2018-03-02  122     A     137             NaN
    2018-03-03  123     A     171             NaN
    2018-01-02    1     B      86             NaN
    2018-01-03    2     B     141             NaN
    2018-01-04    3     B     189             NaN
    2018-01-05    4     B      60             NaN
    2018-01-07    6     B       1             NaN
    2018-01-10    9     B      87             NaN
    2018-01-13   12     B      44             NaN
    2018-01-16   15     B     147             NaN
    2018-01-20   19     B      92             NaN
    2018-01-24   23     B      81             NaN
    2018-01-27   26     B     190             NaN
    2018-01-28   27     B      24             NaN
    2018-01-29   28     B     116             NaN
    2018-01-31   30     B      98        1.181818
    2018-02-01   31     B     121             NaN
    2018-02-02   32     B     110             NaN
    2018-02-03   33     B      66             NaN
    2018-02-05   35     B       4             NaN
    2018-02-06   36     B      13             NaN
    2018-02-09   39     B     114             NaN
    2018-02-11   41     B      16             NaN
    2018-02-13   43     B     174             NaN
    2018-02-14   44     B      78             NaN
    2018-02-17   47     B     144             NaN
    2018-02-18   48     B      14             NaN
    2018-02-20   50     B     133             NaN
    2018-02-22   52     B     156             NaN
    2018-02-23   53     B     159             NaN
    2018-02-24   54     B     177             NaN
    2018-02-25   55     B      43             NaN
    2018-02-28   58     B      19       -0.338542
    2018-03-02   60     B     127             NaN
    2018-01-02   63     B       2             NaN
    2018-01-04   65     B      97             NaN
    2018-01-06   67     B       8             NaN
    2018-01-10   71     B      54             NaN
    2018-01-13   74     B     106             NaN
    2018-01-16   77     B      74             NaN
    2018-01-19   80     B     188             NaN
    2018-01-20   81     B     172             NaN
    2018-01-24   85     B      51             NaN
    2018-01-25   86     B      12             NaN
    2018-01-26   87     B      71             NaN
    2018-01-27   88     B     186             NaN
    2018-01-28   89     B     151             NaN
    2018-01-30   91     B     143             NaN
    2018-01-31   92     B      88        1.181818
    2018-02-02   94     B      75             NaN
    2018-02-03   95     B     103             NaN
    2018-02-05   97     B      82             NaN
    2018-02-07   99     B     128             NaN
    2018-02-08  100     B     123             NaN
    2018-02-09  101     B      52             NaN
    2018-02-10  102     B      18             NaN
    2018-02-11  103     B      21             NaN
    2018-02-12  104     B      50             NaN
    2018-02-13  105     B      64             NaN
    2018-02-15  107     B     185             NaN
    2018-02-20  112     B     125             NaN
    2018-02-21  113     B     108             NaN
    2018-02-22  114     B     132             NaN
    2018-02-23  115     B     180             NaN
    2018-02-26  118     B      67             NaN
    2018-02-28  120     B     192       -0.338542
    2018-03-01  121     B      58             NaN
```

Perhaps there is a more concise and pythonic way of doing this.